# How to speed up marker movement when button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

In Google maps API v3, I need to increase speed of a moving marker on button click. Can anyone help me?

Comment: By decreasing the timer interval, Do you have an example? If yes, then edit your post and post some code with a demo (fiddle) example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3c45n6w/16/
I am not getting what should I do in "Increase Speed" button

Comment: Well I've got it working but you'll see problem, I trying to fix that now https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/b3c45n6w/18/

Comment: thank you it is working but due to this, Stop and Start buttons have started behaving strangely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've made it.
**EDIT**

Here is the fiddle url(meets all the OP requirements): https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/b3c45n6w/24/

If you want to increase the speed faster then just decrease the variable speeds faster:
Here is the code:

```
var marker1, map, route, timerhandle;
var timers = [];
var speeds = 300;
var lastpos;
var counter = 0;
var array2 = [];
var cleared = false;
var polies = [];

function increaseSpeed() {

    speeds = speeds - 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timers[i]);
    }
    marker1.setMap(null);
    marker1.setPosition(array2[array2.length - 1]);
    var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pathCoords[counter + 1].lat, pathCoords[counter + 1].lng);

    route.getPath().push(latlng2);

    autoRefresh(map);

}

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {
            lat: pathCoords[0].lat,
            lng: pathCoords[0].lng
        },
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(8.893260000000001, 76.61427),
        map: map
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(8.52426, 76.93668000000001),
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
    });

    //autoRefresh(map);
}

function moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng) {
    marker1.setPosition(latlng);
    map.panTo(latlng);
}

function autoRefresh(map) {
    var i;
    route = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        editable: false,
        map: map
    });
    polies.push(route);


    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
    });
    for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {

        var timerhandle = setTimeout(function () {
            counter++;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pathCoords[counter].lat, pathCoords[counter].lng);
            array2.push(latlng);
            route.getPath().push(array2[array2.length - 1]);
            moveMarker(map, marker1, array2[array2.length - 1]);

        }, speeds * i, pathCoords[i]);
        timers.push(timerhandle);
    }
}

function stop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timers[i]);
    }
    route.setMap(null);
    marker1.setMap(null);
    marker1 = [];
    cleared = true;
    counter = 0;
    speeds = 300;

    for (k = 0; k < polies.length; k++) {

        polies[k].setMap(null); //or line[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}

var pathCoords = [{
    "lat": 8.893260000000001,
        "lng": 76.61427
}, {
    "lat": 8.894430000000002,
        "lng": 76.61418
}, {
    "lat": 8.89484,
        "lng": 76.61416000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.894860000000001,
        "lng": 76.61383000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.89488,
        "lng": 76.61375000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.89563,
        "lng": 76.61370000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.896270000000001,
        "lng": 76.61366000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.896700000000001,
        "lng": 76.61364
}, {
    "lat": 8.89671,
        "lng": 76.61351
}, {
    "lat": 8.896740000000001,
        "lng": 76.61312000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.89675,
        "lng": 76.61307000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.89677,
        "lng": 76.61305
}, {
    "lat": 8.89729,
        "lng": 76.61303000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.89755,
        "lng": 76.61311
}, {
    "lat": 8.898050000000001,
        "lng": 76.61311
}, {
    "lat": 8.898280000000002,
        "lng": 76.61321000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.899180000000001,
        "lng": 76.61289000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.900350000000001,
        "lng": 76.61396
}, {
    "lat": 8.900860000000002,
        "lng": 76.61467
}, {
    "lat": 8.90127,
        "lng": 76.61581000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.901710000000001,
        "lng": 76.61796000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.902190000000001,
        "lng": 76.61932
}, {
    "lat": 8.902370000000001,
        "lng": 76.62017
}, {
    "lat": 8.902370000000001,
        "lng": 76.62088
}, {
    "lat": 8.902460000000001,
        "lng": 76.6212
}, {
    "lat": 8.90313,
        "lng": 76.62217000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.903450000000001,
        "lng": 76.62240000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.903970000000001,
        "lng": 76.62272
}, {
    "lat": 8.90409,
        "lng": 76.62280000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.904,
        "lng": 76.62288000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.90342,
        "lng": 76.6233
}, {
    "lat": 8.902560000000001,
        "lng": 76.62386000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.90033,
        "lng": 76.62522000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.89601,
        "lng": 76.62777000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.88676,
        "lng": 76.63327000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.884450000000001,
        "lng": 76.63461000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.882610000000001,
        "lng": 76.63582000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.88089,
        "lng": 76.63711
}, {
    "lat": 8.87918,
        "lng": 76.63862
}, {
    "lat": 8.87785,
        "lng": 76.63936000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.875760000000001,
        "lng": 76.63996
}, {
    "lat": 8.87273,
        "lng": 76.64141000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.87067,
        "lng": 76.64251
}, {
    "lat": 8.869280000000002,
        "lng": 76.64336
}, {
    "lat": 8.86805,
        "lng": 76.6447
}, {
    "lat": 8.86782,
        "lng": 76.6451
}, {
    "lat": 8.86677,
        "lng": 76.64822000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.86645,
        "lng": 76.64933
}, {
    "lat": 8.866200000000001,
        "lng": 76.65092
}, {
    "lat": 8.86546,
        "lng": 76.6533
}, {
    "lat": 8.86508,
        "lng": 76.65451
}, {
    "lat": 8.86495,
        "lng": 76.65667
}, {
    "lat": 8.864880000000001,
        "lng": 76.65962
}, {
    "lat": 8.86519,
        "lng": 76.66080000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.866240000000001,
        "lng": 76.66343
}, {
    "lat": 8.86646,
        "lng": 76.66454
}, {
    "lat": 8.866200000000001,
        "lng": 76.66933
}, {
    "lat": 8.86569,
        "lng": 76.67323
}, {
    "lat": 8.86522,
        "lng": 76.67823
}, {
    "lat": 8.863840000000001,
        "lng": 76.68872
}, {
    "lat": 8.86359,
        "lng": 76.6907
}, {
    "lat": 8.86364,
        "lng": 76.69282000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.86317,
        "lng": 76.69574
}, {
    "lat": 8.863420000000001,
        "lng": 76.69850000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.8634,
        "lng": 76.69958000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.863050000000001,
        "lng": 76.70048000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.862350000000001,
        "lng": 76.70149
}, {
    "lat": 8.862020000000001,
        "lng": 76.70239000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.86176,
        "lng": 76.70448
}, {
    "lat": 8.86218,
        "lng": 76.70703
}, {
    "lat": 8.863180000000002,
        "lng": 76.70957
}, {
    "lat": 8.8636,
        "lng": 76.71115
}, {
    "lat": 8.86382,
        "lng": 76.71257
}, {
    "lat": 8.86383,
        "lng": 76.71368000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.86354,
        "lng": 76.71509
}, {
    "lat": 8.863240000000001,
        "lng": 76.71595
}, {
    "lat": 8.86259,
        "lng": 76.71731000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.861540000000002,
        "lng": 76.71883000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.85947,
        "lng": 76.72208
}, {
    "lat": 8.85875,
        "lng": 76.72339000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.8573,
        "lng": 76.72554000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.85478,
        "lng": 76.72876000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.85397,
        "lng": 76.72962000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.8518,
        "lng": 76.73123000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.851220000000001,
        "lng": 76.73173000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.850200000000001,
        "lng": 76.73293000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.84966,
        "lng": 76.73342000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.848920000000001,
        "lng": 76.73382000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.84797,
        "lng": 76.73409000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.84509,
        "lng": 76.73453
}, {
    "lat": 8.843850000000002,
        "lng": 76.73492
}, {
    "lat": 8.84294,
        "lng": 76.73541
}, {
    "lat": 8.841140000000001,
        "lng": 76.73677
}, {
    "lat": 8.84003,
        "lng": 76.73747
}, {
    "lat": 8.838830000000002,
        "lng": 76.73848000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.836,
        "lng": 76.73998
}, {
    "lat": 8.835310000000002,
        "lng": 76.74063000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.83496,
        "lng": 76.74137
}, {
    "lat": 8.834480000000001,
        "lng": 76.74313000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.83385,
        "lng": 76.74406
}, {
    "lat": 8.832690000000001,
        "lng": 76.74528000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.83188,
        "lng": 76.74599
}, {
    "lat": 8.830480000000001,
        "lng": 76.7467
}, {
    "lat": 8.82831,
        "lng": 76.74775000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.82764,
        "lng": 76.74836
}, {
    "lat": 8.82665,
        "lng": 76.7493
}, {
    "lat": 8.82475,
        "lng": 76.7505
}, {
    "lat": 8.82245,
        "lng": 76.75188
}, {
    "lat": 8.82136,
        "lng": 76.75254000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.819880000000001,
        "lng": 76.75371000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.818140000000001,
        "lng": 76.75496000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.815700000000001,
        "lng": 76.75652000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.8125,
        "lng": 76.75867000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.809470000000001,
        "lng": 76.76091000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.806270000000001,
        "lng": 76.76203000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.804110000000001,
        "lng": 76.763
}, {
    "lat": 8.803410000000001,
        "lng": 76.76368000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.802990000000001,
        "lng": 76.76439
}, {
    "lat": 8.8024,
        "lng": 76.76629000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.80207,
        "lng": 76.76687000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.801540000000001,
        "lng": 76.76747
}, {
    "lat": 8.79983,
        "lng": 76.76870000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.799180000000002,
        "lng": 76.76894
}, {
    "lat": 8.798390000000001,
        "lng": 76.76903
}, {
    "lat": 8.79742,
        "lng": 76.76905000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.795710000000001,
        "lng": 76.76929000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.79439,
        "lng": 76.76955000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.79053,
        "lng": 76.77083
}, {
    "lat": 8.78954,
        "lng": 76.77144000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.788820000000001,
        "lng": 76.77241000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.78842,
        "lng": 76.77367000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.78814,
        "lng": 76.77574000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.78767,
        "lng": 76.77690000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.78735,
        "lng": 76.77735000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.78688,
        "lng": 76.77771000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.78307,
        "lng": 76.78025000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.779250000000001,
        "lng": 76.78346
}, {
    "lat": 8.77712,
        "lng": 76.78488
}, {
    "lat": 8.77275,
        "lng": 76.78745
}, {
    "lat": 8.770980000000002,
        "lng": 76.78802
}, {
    "lat": 8.76699,
        "lng": 76.78881000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.765640000000001,
        "lng": 76.78967
}, {
    "lat": 8.76401,
        "lng": 76.79095000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.763190000000002,
        "lng": 76.79128
}, {
    "lat": 8.76102,
        "lng": 76.79195
}, {
    "lat": 8.7558,
        "lng": 76.79388
}, {
    "lat": 8.75234,
        "lng": 76.79589
}, {
    "lat": 8.750900000000001,
        "lng": 76.79650000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.75009,
        "lng": 76.79726000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.748840000000001,
        "lng": 76.79895
}, {
    "lat": 8.747110000000001,
        "lng": 76.80017000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.74582,
        "lng": 76.80142000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.74407,
        "lng": 76.80305000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.74125,
        "lng": 76.80436
}, {
    "lat": 8.73728,
        "lng": 76.80730000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.73624,
        "lng": 76.80879
}, {
    "lat": 8.73544,
        "lng": 76.80953000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.732800000000001,
        "lng": 76.8109
}, {
    "lat": 8.731950000000001,
        "lng": 76.8113
}, {
    "lat": 8.730500000000001,
        "lng": 76.81166
}, {
    "lat": 8.72644,
        "lng": 76.81249000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.723980000000001,
        "lng": 76.81252
}, {
    "lat": 8.72197,
        "lng": 76.81271000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.720460000000001,
        "lng": 76.81268
}, {
    "lat": 8.71958,
        "lng": 76.81273
}, {
    "lat": 8.71719,
        "lng": 76.81297
}, {
    "lat": 8.71636,
        "lng": 76.81293000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.714080000000001,
        "lng": 76.81215
}, {
    "lat": 8.713080000000001,
        "lng": 76.81175
}, {
    "lat": 8.71254,
        "lng": 76.8117
}, {
    "lat": 8.71188,
        "lng": 76.81176
}, {
    "lat": 8.71118,
        "lng": 76.81200000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.70936,
        "lng": 76.81330000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.70716,
        "lng": 76.81486000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.70616,
        "lng": 76.81506
}, {
    "lat": 8.70514,
        "lng": 76.81497
}, {
    "lat": 8.70363,
        "lng": 76.81461
}, {
    "lat": 8.70148,
        "lng": 76.81371
}, {
    "lat": 8.70063,
        "lng": 76.81357000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.70003,
        "lng": 76.81360000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.698400000000001,
        "lng": 76.81366000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.698210000000001,
        "lng": 76.81378000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.69705,
        "lng": 76.81499000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.696520000000001,
        "lng": 76.81584000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.69635,
        "lng": 76.81654
}, {
    "lat": 8.695580000000001,
        "lng": 76.8182
}, {
    "lat": 8.69529,
        "lng": 76.81865
}, {
    "lat": 8.694780000000002,
        "lng": 76.81908
}, {
    "lat": 8.69355,
        "lng": 76.81999
}, {
    "lat": 8.6928,
        "lng": 76.82099000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.691880000000001,
        "lng": 76.82178
}, {
    "lat": 8.690430000000001,
        "lng": 76.82248000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.68914,
        "lng": 76.82319000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.68819,
        "lng": 76.82406
}, {
    "lat": 8.68773,
        "lng": 76.82423
}, {
    "lat": 8.68612,
        "lng": 76.82438
}, {
    "lat": 8.68462,
        "lng": 76.82435000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.68229,
        "lng": 76.82445000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.68044,
        "lng": 76.82475000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.67947,
        "lng": 76.8251
}, {
    "lat": 8.678650000000001,
        "lng": 76.82560000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.678180000000001,
        "lng": 76.82599
}, {
    "lat": 8.67652,
        "lng": 76.82787
}, {
    "lat": 8.67533,
        "lng": 76.82933000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.67463,
        "lng": 76.83056
}, {
    "lat": 8.6738,
        "lng": 76.83302
}, {
    "lat": 8.67337,
        "lng": 76.83368
}, {
    "lat": 8.67276,
        "lng": 76.83424000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.67102,
        "lng": 76.83500000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.669350000000001,
        "lng": 76.83574
}, {
    "lat": 8.6684,
        "lng": 76.83630000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.665890000000001,
        "lng": 76.83818000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.66487,
        "lng": 76.83893
}, {
    "lat": 8.66254,
        "lng": 76.83997000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.66042,
        "lng": 76.8408
}, {
    "lat": 8.65906,
        "lng": 76.84094
}, {
    "lat": 8.65737,
        "lng": 76.84088000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.655100000000001,
        "lng": 76.84037000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.654060000000001,
        "lng": 76.84041
}, {
    "lat": 8.65291,
        "lng": 76.84082000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.65094,
        "lng": 76.84149000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.647400000000001,
        "lng": 76.84214
}, {
    "lat": 8.64208,
        "lng": 76.84372
}, {
    "lat": 8.63718,
        "lng": 76.84567000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.633890000000001,
        "lng": 76.84642000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.63049,
        "lng": 76.84713
}, {
    "lat": 8.62597,
        "lng": 76.84825000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.62233,
        "lng": 76.84888000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.61796,
        "lng": 76.85015
}, {
    "lat": 8.61705,
        "lng": 76.85052
}, {
    "lat": 8.611970000000001,
        "lng": 76.85444000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.609100000000002,
        "lng": 76.85662
}, {
    "lat": 8.60847,
        "lng": 76.85691000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.60748,
        "lng": 76.85704000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.604790000000001,
        "lng": 76.85632000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.60331,
        "lng": 76.85583000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.601980000000001,
        "lng": 76.85521
}, {
    "lat": 8.60084,
        "lng": 76.85462000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.599530000000001,
        "lng": 76.85423
}, {
    "lat": 8.598180000000001,
        "lng": 76.85446
}, {
    "lat": 8.59272,
        "lng": 76.85616
}, {
    "lat": 8.58853,
        "lng": 76.85780000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.587850000000001,
        "lng": 76.85819000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.58651,
        "lng": 76.85957
}, {
    "lat": 8.58371,
        "lng": 76.86185
}, {
    "lat": 8.58211,
        "lng": 76.86330000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.57942,
        "lng": 76.86524
}, {
    "lat": 8.57592,
        "lng": 76.86807
}, {
    "lat": 8.57488,
        "lng": 76.86879
}, {
    "lat": 8.573540000000001,
        "lng": 76.86953000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.57169,
        "lng": 76.87060000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.56986,
        "lng": 76.87212000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.56779,
        "lng": 76.87364000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.56587,
        "lng": 76.87492
}, {
    "lat": 8.56545,
        "lng": 76.8755
}, {
    "lat": 8.565230000000001,
        "lng": 76.87642000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.56508,
        "lng": 76.87809
}, {
    "lat": 8.5647,
        "lng": 76.88276
}, {
    "lat": 8.56473,
        "lng": 76.88329
}, {
    "lat": 8.56521,
        "lng": 76.88474000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.56591,
        "lng": 76.88702
}, {
    "lat": 8.566840000000001,
        "lng": 76.88966
}, {
    "lat": 8.566930000000001,
        "lng": 76.89045
}, {
    "lat": 8.56609,
        "lng": 76.89177000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.564670000000001,
        "lng": 76.89337
}, {
    "lat": 8.56283,
        "lng": 76.89437000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.56193,
        "lng": 76.89489
}, {
    "lat": 8.5616,
        "lng": 76.89528
}, {
    "lat": 8.561290000000001,
        "lng": 76.89592
}, {
    "lat": 8.560770000000002,
        "lng": 76.89757
}, {
    "lat": 8.5608,
        "lng": 76.89906
}, {
    "lat": 8.56107,
        "lng": 76.90019000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.560960000000001,
        "lng": 76.90051000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.560640000000001,
        "lng": 76.90077000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.560080000000001,
        "lng": 76.90137
}, {
    "lat": 8.559880000000001,
        "lng": 76.90159000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.55888,
        "lng": 76.90188
}, {
    "lat": 8.557310000000001,
        "lng": 76.90271000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.55607,
        "lng": 76.90337000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.55532,
        "lng": 76.90364000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.554450000000001,
        "lng": 76.90429
}, {
    "lat": 8.55367,
        "lng": 76.90523
}, {
    "lat": 8.552750000000001,
        "lng": 76.90672
}, {
    "lat": 8.55192,
        "lng": 76.90914000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.551060000000001,
        "lng": 76.91055
}, {
    "lat": 8.55096,
        "lng": 76.91157000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.55077,
        "lng": 76.91293
}, {
    "lat": 8.549750000000001,
        "lng": 76.91429000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.54897,
        "lng": 76.91604000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.54884,
        "lng": 76.91713
}, {
    "lat": 8.54833,
        "lng": 76.91862
}, {
    "lat": 8.548340000000001,
        "lng": 76.91954000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.548340000000001,
        "lng": 76.92013
}, {
    "lat": 8.548150000000001,
        "lng": 76.92067
}, {
    "lat": 8.54765,
        "lng": 76.92168000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.547320000000001,
        "lng": 76.92183
}, {
    "lat": 8.546460000000002,
        "lng": 76.92172000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.54588,
        "lng": 76.92167
}, {
    "lat": 8.545010000000001,
        "lng": 76.92194
}, {
    "lat": 8.54223,
        "lng": 76.92337
}, {
    "lat": 8.54024,
        "lng": 76.92455000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.539470000000001,
        "lng": 76.92527000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.53843,
        "lng": 76.92589000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.536340000000001,
        "lng": 76.92666000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.535070000000001,
        "lng": 76.92738
}, {
    "lat": 8.5333,
        "lng": 76.92876000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.53275,
        "lng": 76.92896
}, {
    "lat": 8.5325,
        "lng": 76.92898000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.530420000000001,
        "lng": 76.92887
}, {
    "lat": 8.530040000000001,
        "lng": 76.92898000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.52973,
        "lng": 76.92966000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.529630000000001,
        "lng": 76.93037000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.52961,
        "lng": 76.93189000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.52964,
        "lng": 76.93216000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.529430000000001,
        "lng": 76.93264
}, {
    "lat": 8.52898,
        "lng": 76.93319000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.5289,
        "lng": 76.93355000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.528920000000001,
        "lng": 76.93416
}, {
    "lat": 8.52889,
        "lng": 76.93433
}, {
    "lat": 8.528680000000001,
        "lng": 76.93433
}, {
    "lat": 8.52801,
        "lng": 76.93436000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.527470000000001,
        "lng": 76.93437
}, {
    "lat": 8.52581,
        "lng": 76.93447
}, {
    "lat": 8.52491,
        "lng": 76.93469
}, {
    "lat": 8.52449,
        "lng": 76.93471000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.524170000000002,
        "lng": 76.93523
}, {
    "lat": 8.52411,
        "lng": 76.93534000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.52424,
        "lng": 76.93537
}, {
    "lat": 8.5244,
        "lng": 76.93548000000001
}, {
    "lat": 8.524370000000001,
        "lng": 76.9364
}, {
    "lat": 8.52426,
        "lng": 76.93668000000001
}];

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Since there are multiple poly-lines involved now, I decided to put them in a array and once hitting the stop button a for loop goes through the array and sets all poly-lines to null, therefore the whole route is cleared and there are no more line on it.

Comment: same problem that I mentioned in previous comment, plus it is making distorted polylines

Comment: @I.Ubaid here is the updated fiddle, but somehow I can not get the route removed https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/b3c45n6w/22/

Comment: okay thank you so much, I'll try to remove the route by myself

Comment: I should do a code revision, but really don't have time for that, and to be honest the route.setMap(null) should do the job but it doesn't.

Comment: yes, anyways thank you

Comment: okay, now I know the problem. Whenever I click the "Increase Speed" button, a new polyline starts from that point and that's why when I click "Stop" button, the route removes only latest polyline

Comment: @I.Ubaid Check out the fiddle now.

Comment: it's working now, thank you so much

Comment: @I.Ubaid you could at least mark the answer solved xd